# Explanation for large inflows into bank account: UK visa for Indian Citizen

Tags: visas, uk, proof-of-funds

I have liquidated some savings which will be transferred online into my bank account by the brokerage firm. As it was suggested here that a note of explanation is not enough, would it be enough if, along with my bank account statement, I get a statement of holdings, say before the sale, and as of date, showing that corresponding value has been sold from those holdings, and the proceeds transferred into my account? After reading some other posts here, I realise that Ive done exactly what I shoudn't have - liquidated savings just at the time of the visa application. I do however have emails from the broker saying this is the sale amount, in addition to the earlier statements I mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have been holding/selling securities, you should include 3 - 6 months of broker statements or a similar statement showing how you acquired them.

And yes, the sale or liquidation of one account should tie out to the deposit into your current account.  You can include a statement that contains a table like...

```
Date        Transaction              Proceeds      Description
xx/xx/xx    Sale of XYZ             12345.50       Broker account
yy/yy/yy    Deposit                 12345.50       Current account
```

NOTE:  this is the way a solicitor would handle your circumstances.  There is nothing in the guidance indicating that all of this is necessary. It is [best practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_practice) and any suitable demonstration that accomplishes the same thing will be fine.  If you think that the decision-maker will be satisfied with something less baroque, go with that instead.

Overall, the controlling legal authority is the deceptively simple phrase in Paragraph V 4.2 (e):  *"`must have sufficient funds`"* with significant emphasis on the single word "**have**" and how this word is [interpreted in the field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_rule).  There are lots of refusals coming from applicants who don't pay attention to the actual words and what they mean.  So you can take a hint from [best practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_practice) and that part of your application should be OK.

Comment: Makes sense. But I would like to add, given the difference in valuation between our currencies, it costs us a small fortune to travel to these countries, and it would be abnormal to keep such large amounts idle in a savings account when it can earn so much more in investments. Ergo, it makes sense to liquidate only when it is needed?

Comment: Yes. It does make sense

Comment: Brilliant advice from this site and we got our visa in three working days!  @Gayot Fow, the advice on provenance really helped me do the paper work properly!

Comment: @Radhika, glad it all worked out.  It's really quite easy once you get the hang of it :)